# Segmentation fault on calling pthread_create, passing a struct

Tags: c, pthreads

I am working on something that needs pthread usage. Basically, I want to find the max on a matrix, but instead of doing all the work single-processed, I use `pthreads` to break it. 
I use one struct, as defined below to enter multiple values to the `findMaxPerArea` function. The problem occurs, when I call `pthread_create(...);` there at the last line. The `printf` before it passes just fine. 
Please don't be too hard on me, because I know this MUST be a stupid mistake. Any thoughts?

```
struct inputData{
  int ** array;
  int start, stop, cols, threadID;
  int* localmax;
};


void* findMaxPerArea(void* tmp){
  struct inputData* inp = (struct inputData*) tmp;
  inp->localmax[inp->threadID] = 0;
  int i, j;
  for(i = inp->start; i < inp->stop; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < inp->cols; j++){
      if(inp->array[i][j] > inp->localmax[inp->threadID]) inp->localmax[inp->threadID] = inp->array[i][j];
    }
  }
}


int main(){
  int N, p;

  printf("Give me the number of threads\n");
  scanf("%d", &p);
  printf("Give me the number of rows and columns (one value)\n");
  scanf("%d", &N);

  int* localmax = malloc(p * sizeof(int));
  pthread_t* threadArr = (pthread_t*) malloc(p*sizeof(pthread_t));

  int** a = malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    a[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
      a[i][j] = 5;
    }
  }
  a[0][1] = 8;
  a[1][1] = 13;
        struct inputData* inputArray = (struct inputData*) malloc(p * sizeof(struct inputData));
          for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){
            inputArray[i].array = a;
            inputArray[i].start = i*(N/p);
            inputArray[i].stop = (N/p)*(i+1) - 1;
            inputArray[i].cols = N;
            inputArray[i].threadID = i;
            inputArray[i].localmax = localmax;
            printf("It passes this\n");
            pthread_create((pthread_t*)threadArr[i], NULL, findMaxPerArea, (void*)&inputArray[i]);
          }}
```

Comment: With the current code snippet you are showing us, it is very hard to reason about your code. Please extent your question to feature a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I updated my answer, this is the whole code I have.

Comment: Don't use casts. It's that simple. (No, actually not that simple. Sometimes you have to. But as the first approximation this rule works. You can spend years and years doing C without writing a single cast. When you finally need one, you are hopefully experienced enough to do it right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pthread_create((pthread_t*)threadArr[i], NULL, findMaxPerArea, (void*)&inputArray[i]);
```

Casting `threadArr[i]` to `pthread_t*` makes no sense, since you cast a value to a pointer. You instead want to omit the cast completely (since you're already dealing with an array of `pthread_t`s) and take the address of the `i`th element:

```
&threadArr[i]
```

Comment: @GusAndrianos You're welcome, but please don't use any swear words here on StackOverflow, it is not at all well received and might get your questions and answers deleted.

Comment: Sorry, but I was searching for almost an hour.